# Outlet react-router-dom not working with react mfe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend

I have exposed RouteProvider from the mfe1

```
exposes: {
        './OverviewApp': './src/RouteProvider/RouteProvider',
      },
```

mfe1 RouteProvider

```
const RouteProvider = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/overview" element={<Overview />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default RouteProvider;
```

Inside Container/Main app I have RouteProvider

```
const RouteProvider = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PrivateRoute />} >
        <Route index path="/overview/*" element={<Overview />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default RouteProvider;
```

Then PrivateRoute

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import PageLayout from "../pagelayout/pagelayout";

const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  return (
    <>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <PageLayout />
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Navigate to="/login" />
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Then PageLayout

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
const Overview = lazy(() => import("Overview/OverviewApp"));
const PageLayout = () => {
  const [pageWidth, setPageWidth] = useState < number > 0;
  return (
    <Grid item container sx={{ mx: "auto" }}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Header />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <Overview /> // when I write directly overview it works but when I use Outlet it does
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <SideMenu />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default PageLayout;
```

Here when I write directly `Overview` it works but when I use `Outlet` it does even I have used it inside the Route of `PrivateRoute`.
Is `Outlet` does not work with micro frontend or I am missing here?